# How to insert array into $_SESSION() from extract function()?

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have a function `get_teacher_info()` in my home.php file. 
It returns an array from the mysql query. 
I stored it in `$data` variable.

Now I want to set each of those `'key'=>'value'` pair in the array as individual variables. So I am using `extract()`

How do I set the session variables that I recive from `extract()`

My code below.

```
$data = $teacher->get_teacher_info();
$_SESSION[]= extract($data);
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `extract` in this case.

Comment: You could use array_merge, but I would recomend you do `$_SESSION['teacher'] = $data;`

Comment: @krishnaRao what is the return type of the data you are getting from `$teacher->get_teacher_info()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
$data = $teacher->get_teacher_info();

// if there is addtional data in the `$_SESSION` before assigning data extracted from DB you can use the `array_merge`, this will keep previous data from `$_SESSION`
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $data);

// If there is no additional data then directly assign the data from DB to `$_SESSION` only if the `$data` is already an associative array
$_SESSION = $data;
```

Comment: @ArjunJGowda Please read the additional comment which I have added.

Comment: Yes if $data has associative array this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your session like this, But a var dump would be more informative

```php
    $data = $teacher->get_teacher_info();
    if(is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
```

And then you can create a Global function to access the value like this

```php
    function getData($key){
        if(array_key_exists($key,$_SESSION)){
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```